# Convert aggregated data frame to data frame with nrow~ n Group elements and ncol ~ n elements of listed vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

I applied a function to a data frame like this

```
> head(df,16)
   ID    Area time
1   1 182.685    1
2   2 182.714    1
3   3 182.275    1
4   4 211.928    1
5   5 218.804    1
6   6 183.445    1
7   7 209.161    1
8   8 205.231    1
9   1 189.743    2
10  2 190.164    2
11  3 189.310    2
12  4 222.414    2
13  5 229.056    2
14  6 191.121    2
15  7 219.344    2
16  8 214.662    2
> autocorr1 <- aggregate(x=df$Area,by=list(df$ID), FUN=acf.fft)
```

..and I got this data frame:

```
  Group.1 x
1       1 c(1, 0.925757424630699, 0.858465741115086, 0.7..
```

I would like to convert it to such a data frame:

```
Group.1 x1                x2                 x3   
1     1  1 0.925757424630699  0.858465741115086  0.7..
```

I tried `as.data.frame(unlist())` and `lapply`, but both give me a concatenated single column data frame:

```
test1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(autocorr1$x, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
test2 <- as.data.frame(unlist(autocorr1$x))
```

Comment: where is `acf.fft` from?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/FHedin/05d4d6d74e67922dfad88038b04f621c

Comment: I must be missing something, using the exact you provided I get a nice data frame as output.

Comment: @Haboryme use `str` and you will see

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `dplyr` and `tidyr` package as follows,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 summarise(new = toString(acf.fft(Area))) %>% 
 separate(new, c(paste0('X', 1:ncol(.))), ', ')

# A tibble: 8 × 3
#     ID    X1    X2
#* <int> <chr> <chr>
#1     1     1    -1
#2     2     1    -1
#3     3     1    -1
#4     4     1    -1
#5     5     1    -1
#6     6     1    -1
#7     7     1    -1
#8     8     1    -1
```

However, If you want to use only base R, then you can `split`, `apply`, and `rbind`, i.e.

```
setNames(data.frame(unique(df$ID) ,do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df, df$ID),function(i) 
                                   acf.fft(i$Area)))), c('ID',paste0('X', 1:max(df$time))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get errors and warnings: `Too many values at 303 locations:` for the `dplyr` and `tidyr` based solution and for the base R solution I get `In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 9)`

Comment: does this `do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df, df$ID),function(i)acf.fft(i$Area)))` work?

Comment: Sorry, gives me the same warning: `In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 9)`. Maybe you need the whole data frame to reproduce... https://justpaste.it/12m03

Comment: this? `plyr::rbind.fill(lapply(split(df1, df1$ID),function(i) as.data.frame(t(acf.fft(i$Area)))))`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in a compact way with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, as.list(acf.fft(Area)) , ID]
#   ID V1 V2
#1:  1  1 -1
#2:  2  1 -1
#3:  3  1 -1
#4:  4  1 -1 
#5:  5  1 -1
#6:  6  1 -1
#7:  7  1 -1
#8:  8  1 -1
```